# Structuremap - How to register certain types in certain layers

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, ioc-container, structuremap

I am using the Registry DSL example to configure structuremap. But doing this makes all of my registered types available in all layers of my application where I add a refernce to structure map. I dont want my business layer to know anything about my data access layer and vice versa. How do I get structuremap to only register specific types for each of my layers?

Here is the code in my global.asax file:

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
{
  x.AddRegistry<RegistryIOC>();
});
```

And here is my RegistryIOC class:

```
public class RegistryIOC : SMRegistry
{

    public RegistryIOC() 
    {
        For<IProfileService>.Use<ProfileService>();
        For<IProctorService>().Use<ProctorService>();

        //Business Logic Objects
        For<IQual>().Use<Qual>();
        For<ITest>().Use<Test>();
        For<IBoldface>().Use<Boldface>();
        For<ITrainingPlan>().Use<TrainingPlan>();
        For<IUnit>().Use<Unit>();

        //Data Transfer Objects
        For<IGenericDTO>().Use<GenericDTO>();
        For<IProfileDTO>().Use<ProfileDTO>();
        For<IQualDTO>().Use<QualDTO>();
        For<IPermissionDTO>().Use<PermissionDTO>();

        //Repository Objects
        For<IProctorRepository>().Use<ProctorRepository>();
        For<IQualsRepository>().Use<QualsRepository>();
        For<ITestRepository>().Use<TestRepository>();
        For<IUnitRepository>().Use<UnitRepository>();
        For<IUserRepository>().Use<UserRepository>();
    }

}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What kind of layers are you talking about? Different processes? Different Machines? If they are all running in the same process, you probably do what your business layer knowing *a little* about your data layer, specifically, its interface. It is unclear what problem you are trying to solve. What is wrong with your RegistryIOC class?

Comment: We have a Service Layer, BLL, and DAL which are all seperate projects. Each project references StructureMap. 

The Service Layer knows about the other two layers but the BLL and the DAL dont know about each other.

I dont want other developers making use of Business Objects from within the DAL and vice versa I dont want developers making use of Repository Objects from within the BLL. The Service Layer orchistrates all of that.

So using the registering all the types this way makes all of the objects vailable across all of our layers (projects).

Comment: Well, *don't* add a reference to StructureMap from any other layer than the Composition Root...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using reflection to accomplish this (and other) tasks. Let me show how that works.

The first thing to do is to define an interface that allows us to identify classes that perform initialization tasks:

```
public interface IConfigurationTask
{
    void Configure();
}
```

Next, create one or more classes that implement this interface. These classes will be spread across all of your projects, which is another way of saying that you can put them "where they belong".

```
public class RepositoryInitializer : IConfigurationTask
{
    public void Configure()
    {
        // code that does relevant initialization goes here
    }
}
```

The last piece of the puzzle is to find classes that implement the IConfigurationTask interface, create an instance of them and execute the Configure method. This is the purpose of the ConfigurationTaskRunner:

```
public static class ConfigurationTaskRunner
{
    public static void Execute( params string[] assemblyNames )
    {
        var assemblies = assemblyNames.Select( Assembly.Load ).Distinct().ToList();
        Execute( assemblies );
    }

    public static void Execute( IEnumerable<Assembly> assemblies )
    {
        var tasks = new List<IConfigurationTask>();
        assemblies.ForEach( a => tasks.AddRange( a.CreateInstances<IConfigurationTask>() ) );

        tasks.ForEach( t => t.Configure() );
    }
}
```

The code shown here uses a custom extension to iterate over all items in a list and execute an action for every item (the ForEach method). I am also using a [reflection library](http://fasterflect.codeplex.com) to make the task of locating and instantiating the instances a one-liner (the CreateInstances method), but you could achieve the same using just plain reflection (as shown in the code below).

```
public static IList<T> CreateInstances<T>( this Assembly assembly )
{
     var query = from type in assembly.GetTypes().Where( t => typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom( t ) && typeof(T) != t ) 
                 where type.IsClass && ! type.IsAbstract && type.GetConstructor( Type.EmptyTypes ) != null 
                 select (T) Activator.CreateInstance( type );
     return query.ToList();
}
```

The final piece of the puzzle is to trigger the execution of the ConfigurationTaskRunner. For example, in a web application this would go into Application_Start in Global.asax:

```
// pass in the names of the assemblies we want to scan, hardcoded here as an example 
ConfigurationTaskRunner.Execute( "Foo.dll", "Foo.Domain.dll" );
```

I've also found it useful with a derived IPrioritizedConfigurationTask (that adds a Priority property) to allow proper ordering of the tasks before you execute them. This is not shown in the example code above, but is fairly trivial to add.

Hope this helps!

Comment: In this example (which is awesome) how do you propose chaining the dependencies?  If I wanted an instance of IProdRepo that was backed by ProdCacheRepo which was backed by ProdRepo...how would you do that chaining?  Curious!

Comment: @AndrewSiemer I suppose that would be the task of the IoC framework (in this case StructureMap), based on the configurations that you supply to it (in the individual Configure methods). The code I provided is merely a mechanism for "distributed configuration" of the IoC container (or whatever else you need initialized on application startup).

Comment: I cant make use of the reflection library. When I try this code via regular reflection, a.CreateInstance("IConfigurationTask"), I get nothing as the result. Maybe I am missing something somewhere... :-(

Comment: @PearWeb I've added a method that does the reflection part without using a 3rd party library. I hope it compiles as I didn't run it through VS first :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create and configure multiple independent `Container` instances and don't use static `ObjectFactory` at all - [see this article](http://codebetter.com/jeremymiller/2008/10/19/using-the-structuremap-container-independent-of-objectfactory/). It'll be then your responsibility to provide proper containers to proper layers.

By the way, how do you want to handle inter-layer communication? Wouldn't it be somehow difficult? I would rather split the registries (possibly to separate assemblies) and keep it decoupled "manually" instead of enforcing decoupling at infrastructure level.

Comment: I dont mind changing my current implementation at all. If its best to have all the registries seperated to classes on each of my layers thats cool with me. Part of my issue is that I dont completely understand how to "provide proper containers to proper layers." What exactly do I put in the global.asax loader?

Comment: Well, generally you'll have to have different entry points for different layers and each layer need to have its own factory method(s) using proper container - this way you'll have separate object graphs for each layer. But I don't really see how to accomplish any interactions between such graphs, so this is why the questions in the second paragraph are. Finally you have to have some kind of upper-layer components X that use lower-level component Y. If X is middle-layer and is created by middle-layer container, so is its dependency Y, even if it is from bottom-layer.

Comment: So generally the answer is it's hard to have totally decoupled object graphs. That's why I suggested decoupling at registry/assembly level, instead of object factory level.